# Quitar el deshabilitado a una etiqueta html con jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

lo que quiero hacer es que dependiendo del resultado de mi funcion cargarOpciones se habilite una etiqueta pero solo cuando se cargue el select si no no se habilite pero no se como hacer la condición el problema es puntual solo requiero saber como plantear el if(){} correctamente.

```js
let cargarOpciones = (select, idSelect, valorCard, valorEstados, valorDistrito, valorProvincia ) => {

     $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: 'cargar_estados.php',
            data:{
                    id:idSelect,
                    valorCard:valorCard,
                    valorEdo:valorEstados,
                    valorDistrito:valorDistrito,
                    valorProvincia:valorProvincia
            },
            dataType:'json'
        })
        .done(function(lista_rep1){
          
            select.empty();
            select.append('<option selected disabled value="0">Seleccione...</option>');
            for (var i = 0; i < lista_rep1.length; i++) {
                select.append('<option value="'+lista_rep1[i][idSelect]+'">'+lista_rep1[i][idSelect]+'</option>');
            };
        })
        .fail(function(){
            alert('error al cargar las listas');
        });
    }
```

```html
 if( cargarOpciones == true){
   selectProvincia.prop( "disabled", false );
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Verifica desde tu lista de resultado.](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_length_array.asp)

```
let esVacio = lista_rep1.length == 0;
select.empty();
select.prop('disabled',esVacio);
select.append('<option selected value="0">Seleccione...</option>');
```

[Y para deshabilitarlo usa la función prop() de jquery](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Answer (score 0):

### $.ajax() método asincrónico

El principal problema que se presenta en tu código (entre otros) es que `$.ajax()` es un método *asincrónico*, por tanto debemos esperar hasta que este se complete para poder evaluar su resultado, en este caso tenemos que usar `setTimeout()` o `setInterval()` para evaluar cada cierto tiempo el resultado.

El siguiente código podrá ayudarte a determinar cuándo `$.ajax()` ya termino:

En tu caso modifica el código de acuerdo al siguiente ejemplo:

```
let cargarOpciones = (select, idSelect, valorCard, valorEstados, valorDistrito, valorProvincia ) => {
     ajax_done = false;
     $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: 'cargar_estados.php',
            data:{
                    id:idSelect,
                    valorCard:valorCard,
                    valorEdo:valorEstados,
                    valorDistrito:valorDistrito,
                    valorProvincia:valorProvincia
            },
            dataType:'json'

     }).done(function(lista_rep1){
            select.empty();
            select.append('<option selected disabled value="0">Seleccione...</option>');
            for (var i = 0; i < lista_rep1.length; i++) {
                select.append('<option value="'+lista_rep1[i][idSelect]+'">'+lista_rep1[i][idSelect]+'</option>');
            };
            ajax_done = true;

     }).fail(function(){
            alert('error al cargar las listas');
            ajax_done = 2;
     });
};
cargarOpciones(select, idSelect, valorCard, valorEstados, valorDistrito, valorProvincia );

waiting_for_AJAX = setInterval(function() {
  if (ajax_done) {
    clearTimeout(waiting_for_AJAX);
    if(ajax_done==true)
      selectProvincia.prop( "disabled", false );
  };
}, 500);
```

Considera replantear tu código ya que aunque esta solución funciona, no deja de ser un método ortodoxo.

En el siguiente ejemplo te dejo una rutina que ejecuta un `callBak()`, que en tu caso seria la forma correcta de replantear el problema:

```js
var A = () => {
 alert("hello word!");
};
var B = (callback) => {
 callback();
};
B(A);
```

Si extrapolamos el ejemplo a tu código, este quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
let cargarOpciones = (select, idSelect, valorCard, valorEstados, valorDistrito, valorProvincia, callback ) => {

     $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: 'cargar_estados.php',
            data:{
                    id:idSelect,
                    valorCard:valorCard,
                    valorEdo:valorEstados,
                    valorDistrito:valorDistrito,
                    valorProvincia:valorProvincia
            },
            dataType:'json'

     }).done(function(lista_rep1){
            select.empty();
            select.append('<option selected disabled value="0">Seleccione...</option>');
            for (var i = 0; i < lista_rep1.length; i++) {
                select.append('<option value="'+lista_rep1[i][idSelect]+'">'+lista_rep1[i][idSelect]+'</option>');
            };
            callback();

     }).fail(function(){
            alert('error al cargar las listas');
     });
};
cargarOpciones(select, idSelect, valorCard, valorEstados, valorDistrito, valorProvincia, function() { selectProvincia.prop( "disabled", false ) });
```

Espero esto te ayude... ;)